# PHP running as a FastCGI application (php-cgi) - how to issue concurrent requests?

Tags: php, concurrency, fastcgi

***EDIT: Update - scroll down***
***EDIT 2: Update - problem solved***

---

**Some background information:**

I'm writing my own webserver in Java and a couple of days ago I asked on SO how exactly Apache interfaces with PHP, so I can implement PHP support. I learnt that FastCGI is the best approach (since mod_php is not an option). So I have looked at the FastCGI protocol specification and have managed to write a working FastCGI wrapper for my server. I have tested phpinfo() and it works, in fact all PHP functions seem to work just fine (posting data, sessions, date/time, etc etc).

My webserver is able to serve requests concurrently (ie user1 can retrieve file1.html at the same time as user2 requesting some_large_binary_file.zip), it does this by spawning a new Java thread for each user request (terminating when completed or user connection with client is cancelled).

However, it cannot deal with 2 (or more) FastCGI requests at the same time. What it does is, it queues them up, so when request 1 is completed immediately thereafter it starts processing request 2. I tested this with 2 PHP pages, one contains sleep(10) and the other phpinfo().

How would I go about dealing with multiple requests as I know it can be done (PHP under IIS runs as FastCGI and it can deal with multiple requests just fine).

**Some more info:**

I am coding under windows and my batch file used to execute php-cgi.exe contains:

```
set PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=500
php-cgi.exe -b 9000
```

But it does not spawn 8 children, the service simply terminates after 500 requests.

I have done research and from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI#Implementation_details):

> Processing of multiple requests
>   simultaneously is achieved either by
>   using a single connection with
>   internal multiplexing (ie. multiple
>   requests over a single connection)
>   and/or by using multiple connections

Now clearly the multiple connections isn't working for me, as everytime a client requests something that involves FastCGI it creates a new socket to the FastCGI application, but it does not work concurrently (it queues them up instead).

I know that internal multiplexing of FastCGI requests under the same connection is accomplished by issuing each unique FastCGI request with a different [request ID](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html#S3.3).
(also see the last 3 paragraphs of 'The Communication Protocol' heading in [this article](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgi/#id2854157)).

I have not tested this, but how would I go about implementing that? I take it I need some kind of FastCGI Java thread which contains a Map of some sort and a static function which I can use to add requests to. Then in the Thread's run() function it would have a while loop and for every cycle it would check whether the Map contains new requests, if so it would assign them a request ID and write them to the FastCGI stream. And then wait for input etc etc, As you can see this becomes too complicated.

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this? Or any thoughts at all? Thanks very much.

*Note, if required I can supply the code for my FastCGI wrapper.*

---

**Update**:

Basically, I downloaded nginx and set it up to use PHP as a FastCGI application and it too suffered from the same problem as my server. It could not handle concurrent PHP requests. This is leads me to believe my code is in fact correct. So something is wrong with PHP or I am not setting it up correctly. Maybe it is because I am using Windows because some lighttpd users claim Windows can't handle FastCGI properly (this doesn't make much sense). I'll install Linux sometime soon and report any progress with that.

Comment: Very well, I just stuck on this problem for a day, and hard to figure out what happen on the sleep() of PHP will affect other process, thanks for your answer and share.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I managed to find the cause of the problem. It wasn't my code at all. It's PHP, it cannot spawn additional php-cgi's under Windows when running as FastCGI mode, under Linux it works perfectly, I simply pointed my server to my linux box IP and it had no problems with concurrent FCGI requests. Sucks, but I guess that's the way it is...

I did look deeper into the PHP source code after that and found that the section of code which responds to PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN has been encapsulated by #ifndef WIN32 So the developers must be aware of the issue

Comment: Update: PHP v7.1+ handles PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN on Windows.  If the env var is defined, the first php-cgi.exe process will exec the specified number of children. These will share the same TCP socket. See [commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/5b91658365562da78cdb00c8d8f697ba340b3fba) and http://php.net/manual/de/migration71.windows-support.php

Comment: @JensA.Koch thanks for pointing that out. but how practical is this implementation. checked the link you posted but I could hardly find any follow up or any discussion on it

Comment: This is practical from the moment on, where you want to run multiple requests to the PHP backend. PHP defaults to no children, one worker. When this one worker is busy, rest of the requests will block. - This is also the reason why all the FCGI spawner tools have been written, before the patch to PHP itself landed. - If you mean "practical" in the sense of how performant this is on Windows in general. Very clear answer: any PHP run on Windows is unpractical, compared to running on Linux. Windows was reasonable as a dev environment (XAMPP, WPN-XM, etc), before Docker envs took over.

Answer (score 3):

Hi this comes a little late, I've wrote a spawner for php-cgi.exe on windows, not perfect but it might be what you needed. Check it at [here](https://bitbucket.org/cybergene/spawn-php/wiki/Home).

Comment: Oh very nice, I'll have a look at that!

Comment: halleluya man, after 2 days of extensive googling and realizing that php-cgi.exe can serve 1 concurrent connection i was desperate to develop locally on apache and on server have nginx, but i wanted to have same setup in both environments. so your solution helped. btw it works only with activepython, because it has ˇwin32processesˇ, the standard python doesnt have that lib

Answer (score 2):

re: spawn-php python script...

Thanks @nosam that really helped.
For those wanting to get it working quickly you'll need the following (if 64bit system)

> ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win64-x64.msi 
> pywin32-217.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

ActivePython does not have older versions of these on their www so you will need to do a bit of googling around to find a working mirror (there are plenty out there)

Once you have downloaded the src from bitbucket you may need to edit spawn-php.py (to fix up the tab spacing), as bit-bucket seemed to mess up the tab's in the file preventing it from running.

All-in-all that saved my day for a busy little windows website using nginx + fast-cgi.

Thanks mate!