# IIS Website - unable to load other pages while cron/ long execution running

Tags: php, iis

Hoping someone has some ideas around what to do with this.
We have a application thats PHP based hosted in IIS.
There are a number of functions that need to run which can be running for 10mins+. The problem I have is that if I run one of these functions in my web browser. If I open another tab and try to access the site while that is happening then it just sits loading until the long process finishes and then it loads the page.

I guess this is more of a multi session thing to my browser? Is there some easy option in IIS I can change that will let it load the other pages as normal? Or is this a browser thing?

It seems if I open an in private window at the same time, that will load normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the session. by default PHP session use a file system.so that has to wait for the session file to be closed before they can open new. Therefore, subsequent requests for the same session wait on prior requests.

To resolve the issue you could try the below things:

-close the session when you are done with it by using the `session_write_close()`

-Implement a custom DB handler which utilizes the database instead of the file system.

Reference:

[FastCGI on IIS7... multiple concurrent requests from same user session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054135/fastcgi-on-iis7-multiple-concurrent-requests-from-same-user-session)