# How to enable loopback connections in Jelastic WordPress Cluster with public IP and external domain?

Tags: wordpress, loopback, jelastic

After installing a WordPress Cluster through the marketplace, giving the environment a public IP address and connecting a external domain with it, the site worked via the external domain for visitors.

But I can't do a lot of things in the backend (as saving a post) - as processes are not ending or throwing an timeout error. Mostly in combination with cURL.

So I tested with WordPress Plugin "Health Check". The negative result was "The loopback request to your site failed"

I read about it and found https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-enable-loopback-connections-on-ubuntu-14-04 - but that seems to not work in the cluster environment, as the hosts file looks different in every app-server - in will look different in new ones (when horizontal auto-scaling adds one), right?

So I would like to know, who I can enable loopback connections in this WordPress Cluster on Jelastic.

THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: "The loopback request no longer works in WP 4.9 and up, and it likely will not be “fixed” because it was an intentional design feature." https://wordpress.org/support/topic/4-91-the-loopback-request-to-your-site-failed/

Comment: @Jelastic You quote from a WP support forum and what you quote doesn't start with "The loopback request no longer works..." - it starts with "This no longer works..." - and "This" doesn't reference to "The loopback request". It references to the sentence "It use to work prior to version 4.9." fromt the person that seeks for help there. She or he says in the conversation, that his wp site worked prior to version 4.9 without his webhost supporting loopback requests. But now WordPress depends on this loopback request. So it is exactly the other way round.

Comment: @Jelastic And loopback connections could be interessting in other scenarios, too. Without WordPress, etc. So perhaps an answer to my question would still be possible?

Comment: Michael, Thanks for the clarifications. Could you please provide more use cases/scenarios for the loopback connections?

Comment: your scenario is now being discussed internally and we'll provide feedback soon. Thanks for the reporting.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Michael, please try to set 24 cloudlets for the nginxphp after the cluster installation. This should help. The case is related to php-fpm workers and described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813667/php-curl-timing-out-but-cli-curl-works