# Can Windows PHP-FPM serve multiple simultaneous requests?

Tags: windows-7, nginx, php

I'm currently using **nginx** and **PHP FastCGI** but that arrangement suffers from the limitation that it can only serve one HTTP request at a time. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793996/php-running-as-a-fastcgi-application-php-cgi-how-to-issue-concurrent-request).) I start PHP from the Windows command prompt by doing;

```
c:\Program Files\PHP>php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

However there is another way to run PHP know as "Fast CGI Process Manager" (PHP-FPM).

When running on Windows 7 behind nginx, can PHP-FPM handle multiple simultaneous HTTP requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up with this solution: you simply start several php-cgi processes and bind them to different ports, and you need to update nginx config:

```
http {

    upstream php_farm {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000 weight=1;
        server 127.0.0.1:9001 weight=1;
        server 127.0.0.1:9002 weight=1;
        server 127.0.0.1:9003 weight=1;
    }

    ...

    server {
      ...
      fastcgi_pass   php_farm;
    }

}
```

---

For the sake of convenience, I created simple batch files.

`start_sandbox.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Starting sandbox...

RunHiddenConsole.exe php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c php\php.ini
RunHiddenConsole.exe php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9001 -c php\php.ini
RunHiddenConsole.exe php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9002 -c php\php.ini
RunHiddenConsole.exe php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9003 -c php\php.ini

RunHiddenConsole.exe mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console

cd nginx && START /B nginx.exe && cd ..
```

and `stop_sandbox.bat`:

```
pstools\pskill php-cgi

pstools\pskill mysqld

pstools\pskill nginx
```

as you can see, there are 2 dependencies: [pstools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) and [runhiddenconsole.exe](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/attachments/660/RunHiddenConsole.zip)

Comment: Thank you. Struggling with it for the last 2 hours.

Answer (score 6):

There is an alternative, as in better way.

Use the simple Fast-CGI setup in your nginx config

nginx.conf

```
server {
     ....
     location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files   $uri =404; 
            include     fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
            allow       127.0.0.1;
            allow       ::1;        
            deny        all;        
       }
  }
```

Then in your start.bat file

```
set PATH=%cd%\bin\php;%PATH%
set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0
set PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=10
RunHiddenConsole.exe %cd%/php/php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9001 -c %cd%/php/php.ini
```

The PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN variable is where the magic happens. PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS is also important.

Comment: Nice timing. Just wanted to create a post somewhere, asking if there really is no simple way of creating PHP-FPM child processes dynamically on Windows too :).

Comment: Works great!!! I was going crazy with only one php-cgi process. Had no idea it was this easy. Thank you!!!