# Running NginX and PHP (CGI) on Windows 10 - No input file specified

Tags: php, mysql, windows, batch-file, nginx

I want to setup a web dev environment on my Windows 10 PC. On my 2nd hard drive (`D:\WebDev`) I have the following:

[image]

This is how my NginX is configured: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JFSX6hfU

So, this is the contents of my **start.bat** file:

```
@ECHO OFF
set PATH=D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16;%PATH%

ECHO Starting...

RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9001
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9002
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9003
RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\php-5.6.16\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9004

RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\WebDev\mariadb-10.1.9\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=D:\WebDev\mariadb-10.1.9\my.ini --standalone --console

cd D:\WebDev\nginx-1.9.7 && START /B nginx.exe && cd ..
```

> This was put together based on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819351/can-windows-php-fpm-serve-multiple-simultaneous-requests/33032959#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819351/can-windows-php-fpm-serve-multiple-simultaneous-requests/33032959#_=_)

When I run `start.bat` file, NginX and MariaDB is getting started (i've verified by visiting `http://localhost` and I can see the `index.html` being served) and I can connect to the MariaDB Server (mysql) with Navicat.

The only thing that isn't working is the PHP. Firstly, I cannot see any PHP processes in the task manager and when I visit `phpinfo()` page, I get the error:

> No input file specified.

Any idea what might be wrong? Sorry if this question is in the wrong site.

Comment: Any news about that? i'm having the same issue

Comment: still waiting... no news yet sorry.