# Why only 6 php fastcgi workers loaded on IIS 8

Tags: php, performance, iis, fastcgi, windows-server-2012

I resize picture on the fly 1 per request via imagick. Every request I create
new imagick object, read original file, resize it and return to browser. This is not faster way but I don't want use cache.

I always waiting until 6 workers will end resizing process for the start next new 6 images.

[image: 6 workers for 6 images]

Max number of php fastcgi workers is 6. And I don't like big queue time.

What can I do with it? Is this fastcgi primary problem?

IIS 8.5, php 5.6 win server 2012

Answer (score 0):

It look like windows is to blame, no fix. I have same problem on Windows Server 2012 R2 but i found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476927/4866851